# retrieving custom object from jBPM6 using REST API

Tags: java, jboss, jbpm

we have created a jBPM workflow where we are passing custom object to create a workitem, we are passing this custom object as  Map params.
Now using REST API "List getTasksAssignedAsPotentialOwnerByStatus" we can retrieve the TaskSummary for assigned userId, here TaskSummary object is predefined with fields, can anybody please guide me if i want to customize my response (i.e. if i want to retrieve additional parameters in the TaskSummary) then how  can i do it using REST API?

Answer (score 0):

The task summary should link a content id (in task data), containing the parameters you passed.  Use this content id to get the content.